# w3wp missing while ms crm remote debugging with crm 2011 and vs 2013

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, remote-debugging, w3wp

I have been debugging for a while and suddenly w3wp has stopped appearing from processes list while choosing to remote debug crm 2011.

I have logged off and on from the CRM Server and closed and started a new remote debugger instance on it as well, also closed and reopened visual studio but still w3wp doesnt appear at all even after MS CRM Async process restart and iisreset

Answer (score 0):

1. Confirm you are running Visual Studio as Administrator
2. Confirm you have selected "Show processes from all users" in the Attach to Process dialog of Visual Studio.
3. Check you have "spawned" the w3p process after an IIS Reset. (you can simply refresh/relaunch the page you are debugging.)